# How does #import search for files in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, import

I can only find a little bit of information on the topic.  My understand right now is that

```
#import <my.h> // searches in the system paths
#import "my.h" // searches in the same dir as the source file - is that right?
```

I have an static library with .h files in a different location. Can I have the compiler search  a new folder for .h files with #import "my.h"  like I would in VC++

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your understanding is pretty much correct, except that `#import "my.h"` searches in the same directory as the source file, *and* all the system paths (the same ones searched by `#import <my.h>`).

> I have an static library with .h files in a different location. Can I have the compiler search a new folder for .h files with #import "my.h" like I would in VC++

Yes. You have to pass the `-I` flag to gcc. For example, if you want to search `path/to/my-other-dir`, you'd pass `-Ipath/to/my-other-dir` to gcc. If you're using Xcode, you can configure this using the build options for your target; look for the option called **Header Search Paths**, under **Search Paths**.

Answer (score 1):

In Objective-C, `#import` is just `#include` which will include each file once only. So it will follow `#include` rules in searching the file.

The `<…>` indicates system headers and `"…"` user headers. Which path the preprocessor will look into depend on the your settings. For GCC, `<…>` will look in:

```
 /usr/local/include
 <libdir/gcc/target/version>/include
 /usr/<target>/include
 /usr/include
```

and also the paths added by the `-I` and `-F` switches. `"…"` will look in current directory, and then those added by the `-iquote` switch, and then the system paths.

See http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Search-Path.html for detail.

Answer (score 0):

Also of relevance

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Include-Syntax.html